# Simple block diagram

Tags: diagrams, arrows, tikz-arrows

I have to ask for your help again. 
I am trying to produce a block diagram, a really simple one.
[image]

So far I have gotten to this part:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{answer} = [rectangle, draw, text width=15em, text badly centered, node distance=1cm, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=30em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
% Place nodes
\node [block] (development) {text};
\node [block, below of=development] (quantitive) {text};
\node [block, below of=quantitive] (significances) {text};
\node [block, below of=significances] (utility) {text};
\node [block, below of=utility] (optimization) {text};
\node [block, below of=optimization] (decide) {text?};\\
\matrix [column sep=2mm,row sep=3mm] {\node [answer, below of=decide, node distance=1cm] (answerno) {text}; & \node [answer, below of=decide, node distance=1cm] (answeryes) {text};\\};
% Draw edges
\path [line] (development) -- (quantitive);
\path [line] (quantitive) -- (significances);
\path [line] (significances) -- (utility);
\path [line] (utility) -- (optimization);
\path [line] (optimization) -- (decide);
\path [line] (decide) -- node {No} (answerno);
\path [line] (decide) -- node {Yes} (answeryes);
\path [line] (answerno) -- (development);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And it produces a nasty view. Is there even an option to have two arrows like that? Or will I have to rethink the diagram design.
Appreciate any suggestions.
*sleeping*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative, more concise code using macros from packages `chain` and `quotes`:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 0mm,
  start chain = A going below,
  base/.style = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners,
                 minimum height=2em, text width=15em, align=flush center,
                 inner sep=2mm},
answer/.style = {base, text width=15em},
 block/.style = {base, text width=32em, on chain, join=by line},
  line/.style = {-Stealth},
                        ]
% Place nodes
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={block}]
\node   {text};         % name: A-1
\node   {text};
\node   {text};
\node   {text};
\node   {text};
\node   {text};         %       A-6
    \end{scope}
\node   (answerno)  [answer, below right=of A-6.south west] {text};
\node   (answeryes) [answer, below  left=of A-6.south east] {text};
% Draw edges
\draw[line] (A-6.south -| answerno.north)     to ["No"] (answerno);
\draw[line] (A-6.south -| answeryes.north)   to ["Yes"] (answeryes);
\draw[line] (answerno.west) -- ++ (-2,0) |- (A-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Some quick improvements:

- `\tikzstyle` is obsolete, use `\tikzset` instead. See my code to see how to use it.
- Although `arrows` is still supported, it's deprecated. You can use it if you prefer, but `arrows.meta` is the current library.
- The library `positioning` should be used, changing from `below of=...`, to `below =of...`.
- The `standalone` class is very useful for showing small examples.
- `\path[draw]` is equivalent to `\draw`, the second means less typing and neater code, though.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    answer/.style={rectangle, draw, text width=15em, text badly centered, node distance=1cm, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=4em},
    block/.style={rectangle, draw, text width=30em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    line/.style={-{Stealth}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 5mm, auto]
% Place nodes
\node [block] (development) {text};
\node [block, below =of development] (quantitive) {text};
\node [block, below =of quantitive] (significances) {text};
\node [block, below =of significances] (utility) {text};
\node [block, below =of utility] (optimization) {text};
\node [block, below =of optimization] (decide) {text?};

\node [answer, below =of decide.south west, anchor=north west] (answerno) {text}; 
\node [answer, below =of decide.south east, anchor=north east] (answeryes) {text};
% Draw edges
\draw[line] (development) -- (quantitive);
\draw[line] (quantitive) -- (significances);
\draw[line] (significances) -- (utility);
\draw[line] (utility) -- (optimization);
\draw[line] (optimization) -- (decide);
\draw[{Stealth}-] (answerno) -- (answerno|-decide.south) node[right, midway] {No};
\draw[{Stealth}-] (answeryes) -- (answeryes|-decide.south) node[right, midway] {Yes};
\draw[line] (answerno.west) -- ++ (-2,0) |- (development.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know this question is old but since this was the #1 Google search result for me, others may benefit from this, too: How would you put another block below the answers, which has the entire width again?